# How can I modify this regular expression to grab the filename from ls -a output?

Tags: regex, linux, ls

Let's say I already have the output of an 'ls -la' command and I now want to parse out just the filenames. I have this regular expression so far that I found, but how can I modify this to account for there being whitespace in the filename itself?

Example 'ls -la' output:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 admin  staff  460340057 May  4 14:19 test_large_file.xml
```

Regular Expression I have so far:

```
\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+(\S+)
```

Comment: I think this might work? But I might be missing something: \S+\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+(\S|\s|-|_|%20)+

Comment: parsing `ls` output in bash is not a good idea

Comment: Try it with `ls -a` as the starting point. May be unnecessary to choose the -l format just to filter it out.

Comment: @ᴳᵁᴵᴰᴼI'm parsing the output in Java after I get the results from an ls command via JSch ... really I'm trying to work around a bug in the JSch library.

Comment: JSch has a bug (or feature) where if there is an alias on the ls command to something like 'ls -la' then the library can't pick up files from the ftp server.

Comment: @anubhava My question states that there could be whitespace in the filename ... so yeah ... there could be whitespace in the filename.

Comment: Well filenames can contain newlines as well

Comment: @anubhava True, it would need to account for that as well.

Comment: `ls` command automatically quotes filenames when it finds whitespace in filenames i.e. `'filename with space'`. Isn't this already happening for you?

Comment: No, it doesn't auto quote filenames with spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
/^.*\d\s+(.*?)$/m
```

https://regex101.com/r/mR4rH1/1

Comment: Does this account for new lines and/or spaces in the filename?

Comment: Yes, it should work with both. You can test it with the regex101 above

Comment: Are you using the regex with sed ?

Comment: No, regex from Java.

Comment: you can use the regex above, just make sure you set `Pattern.MULTILINE`